# XML objectify in Groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

Is there a library for Groovy that introspects XML and provides an object to access each node - like lxml for Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [XmlParser](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser)

Answer (score 2):

Give [XmlSlurper](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_xmlparser_and_xmlslurper) a shot.  It makes consuming the XML and traversing the document almost trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Diff. between XmlParser and XmlSlurper - http://groovy.dzone.com/news/john-wilson-groovy-and-xml *from the creator of XmlSlurper*